# Kotlin JavaScript to TypeScript Definition File

Tags: javascript, typescript, kotlin

I have found the [ts2kt library](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt) which will create Kotlin header files from arbitrary `.d.ts` files.  But, I want to go in the opposite direction.

*I want to build a Kotlin library that will compile to JavaScript, but I want to use it from TypeScript.*  Is there a way to make Kotlin generate a `.d.ts` file(s) from its exposed interfaces?  Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: kotlin does not map 1-to-1 to javascript as typescript does

so even if such tool existed, kotlin types would not represent the generated javascript all the time

Comment: AFAIK such tool is not exist (yet)

Comment: related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Kotlin 1.4-M1 support for exporting TypeScript definitions was added](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/#ts-definitions)

> ###### Preview: TypeScript definitions
>
> Another feature in the new Kotlin/JS IR compiler we’re excited to show off is the generation of TypeScript definitions from Kotlin
> code. These definitions can be used by JavaScript tools and IDEs when
> working on hybrid apps to provide autocompletion, support static
> analyzers, and make it easier to include Kotlin code in JS and TS
> projects.
>
> For top-level declarations marked with `@JsExport` (see above) in a project configured to use `produceExecutable()`, a .`d.ts` file with the
> TypeScript definitions will be generated. For the snippet above, they
> look like this:
>
> ```js
> // [...]
> namespace blogpost {
>     class KotlinGreeter {
>         constructor(who: string)
>         greet(): string
>     }
>     function farewell(who: string): string
> }
> // [...]
> ```
>
> In Kotlin 1.4-M1, these declarations can be found in  `build/js/packages/<package_name>/kotlin` alongside the corresponding,
> un-webpacked JavaScript code. Please note that since this is only a
> preview, they are not added to the distributions folder by default for
> now. You can expect this behavior to change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do something like this to share models between Android and JS. There is the [ts-generator](https://github.com/ntrrgc/ts-generator) library, which takes jvm classes and generates ts definitions from them.

I haven't tried this yet, but it theoretically should work. Separate the API for your library (or an interface the api implements) into a [kotlin common module](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html). You can then compile the api into a jvm module, and run it through the [ts-generator](https://github.com/ntrrgc/ts-generator) to generate ts definitions.

Maybe there is a clever way to do this to skip the compilation to jvm for ts definition generation.

Comment: If you're looking for an easy way to try ts-generator, check out the [ktsgenerator](https://github.com/ayedo/ktsgenerator) Gradle plugin